# Expose grpc for a rest api

Tags: rest, grpc

I have rest services currently in production. The services deal with huge amount of data and we are planning to build an sdk for our clients. Is there a way to expose grpc server side controller code while reusing the existing providers?

Any kind of pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There is this gRPC Gateway project, which might be useful. It generates RESTful API for your protobuf definitions. See https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway.

Comment: Is this exlucively for Go, or can C++ generated code use it as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic way to provide a gRPC version of your REST services.

In order to provide a gRPC service version of your REST, you will need to work on the following steps:

- Translate your current REST request/response contract to [Protobuf](https://github.com/apssouza22/protobuf-api-management/blob/master/protos/local/book/v1/books.proto#L12)
- [Generate a "stub"](https://github.com/apssouza22/protobuf-api-management/blob/master/bin/java-gen.sh) implementation of every service interface for your language
- Build a [gRPC server to respond](https://github.com/apssouza22/protobuf-api-management/blob/master/services/shelf/src/main/java/com/apssouza/shelf/App.java) to your requests.

Your gRPC services would work as a proxy to your REST services, so it will leverage from your REST enpoints, It will basically parse the JSON to gRPC objects

Comment: Just to clarify, isn't the protoc going to generate the proxy and the stub itself from a `service.proto`  ?

Comment: What do you mean by proxy? Protoc only generate stubs and grpc service. A proxy to your rest will be done by you

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 7.0 Microsoft added a GRPC JSON transcoding package, which will allow you to expose your GRPC services as a REST service (but not the other way around):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/json-transcoding?view=aspnetcore-7.0